# Need to get last match in row before returned?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image: Problem Array Formulae]

This array formula works until row 5 . Instead of taking away B6 from C5 it taken B6 from C4. How can I check the formulae to take into account some days may have several logons ? Need to take away last login to get the system out time.[image]

`=IF(SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy"))*($A$1:A5=A6))>0,B6-INDEX($C$1:C10,MATCH(1,($A$1:A5=A6)*(TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy")),0)),0)`

Comment: I remember writing this for you. You probably have to implement `LARGE` on the index instead of the match. Like so: `....INDEX($C$1:C5,LARGE(($A$1:A5=A6)*(TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy"))*ROW($A$1:A5)),1))...`

Comment: U are pretty awesome. Excel is causing me a few issues recently. Let me give you points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to get the largest hit returned, so replace:

```
MATCH(1,($A$1:A5=A6)*(TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy")),0)
```

with something like:

```
LARGE(($A$1:A5=A6)*(TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy"))*ROW($A$1:A5)),1))
```

The whole thing would look like:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy"))*($A$1:A5=A6))>0,B6-INDEX($C$1:C10,LARGE(($A$1:A5=A6)*(TEXT($B$1:B5,"dd-mm-yyyy")=TEXT(B6,"dd-mm-yyyy"))*ROW($A$1:A5),1)),0)
```

I haven't checked so maybe there is an error with one of the brackets, you'll have to check that yourself.

Enter as array obviously!